# How to copy the appropriate config file, with CHEF, in a recipe?

Tags: linux, configuration, chef, package-management

I'm starting to learn how develop `recipes` to `chef`.
I need to install `Ganglia Monitor` in some servers (or `nodes` in ganglia literature).
So that's why I'm checking if the plataform is `ubuntu`, `centOS` and many others to install the correct package.

The issue is that I have two different `.config` files, actually there is only one or two parameters in this `.config` file that would differ one from another.
I need help how to detect in which `datacenter` that the `server` belongs so that I can copy the properly `.config` file. 
So far, I was able to develop this script below, but I have some dobut, which are in comments in the code.

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: ganglia
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2013, Valter Henrique.com
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#
# Installing Ganglia Monitor

case node[:platform]
  when "ubuntu", "debian"
    package "ganglia-monitor"
  when "redhat", "centos", "fedora"
    package "ganglia-gmond"
  end
  user "ganglia"
end

# Setting different .config files
case ipaddress
# DataCenter #1
# how put more options in the when condition ? A when for /^200.222./ or /^200.223./ ?
    when /^200.222./ 
        # putting config file
        cookbook_file "/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf" do
            owner "root"
            group "root"
            mode "0644"
            source "dc1/gmond.conf"
            notifies(:restart, "service[gmond]")
        end
    #DataCenter #2
    when /^216.235./
        cookbook_file "/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf" do
            owner "root"
            group "root"
            mode "0644"
            source "dc2/gmond.conf"
            notifies(:restart, "service[gmond]")
        end
  end
```

Any suggestion in how I develop this code in a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in `source` attribute for `cookbook_file` resource to avoid code duplication.

```
dc = case ipaddress
     when /^200\.222\./
       'dc1'
     when /^216\.235\./
       'dc2'
     end

cookbook_file "/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf" do
   owner "root"
   group "root"
   mode "0644"
   source "#{dc}/gmond.conf"
   notifies(:restart, "service[gmond]")
end
```